# AJAX call broken after actualization

Tags: ajax

I have a simple form, where user can set some numeric value and add a comment. Then it is being send to database via AJAX call.

So I have two inputs: a numeric slider (text field) and a textarea for comment (and of course submit button).

My JavaScript that calls Ajax after clicking the button looks like that:

```
jQuery("button.ocen").click(function(event){


    var dok = jQuery(this).parent().find("input#dok").val(); //  this is always integer
    var comment = jQuery(this).parent().find("#komentarz").val(); // this is string

    var data = {
            action: 'ocen',
            dok: dok,
            comment: comment
    };
     var jqxhr = jQuery.post("http://mydomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response){
        }).done(function(response){
            jQuery(".odpowiedz").html(response);
            setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 1500);
        });        
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

I used this method succesfully for about 7 months. But lately after one of the wordpress' actualizations it stopped to work correctly: If I set only the numeric value, it is being saved to database correctly, but if I add a comment, the page is being reloaded but nothing is being saved to DB.

What can be wrong with it?

EDIT:
the php code:

```
function ajax_ocen()
{
extract($_POST);
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors;
    if(!isset($comment))
        $comment = "";

    $q = "INSERT INTO my_table(date, dok, comment) VALUES(NOW(), $dok, '$comment')";

    $res = $wpdb->query($q);
    if($res)
        echo "<div class='success'>Added</div>";

    $wpdb->show_errors;

exit();
}
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I found out that comment is not being saved if it contains special language-specific characters. How can I escape/convert those charracters to be properly saved to DB?

Comment: Can you post the PHP code?

Comment: Yes - see my edit

Comment: You use `extract($_POST);` and then `$comment` and `$dot`; that expect that the `name` attribute of the textarea is `comment` (`$comment` extracted from `$_POST['comment']`) and the `name` attribute of the input is `dok` (`$dok` extracted from `$_POST['dok']`), are those values correctly set in the `name` attributes? Can you post the HTML also? Aside note: `extract()` was abandoned by WordPress core and, in general, it is not recommended because it makes debugging more difficult, as you can see in this situation.

Comment: Yes, they are correctly set.

Comment: Try to echo the resulting query `$q`. (Also, please use $wpdb->escape() to avoid possible SQL injections.)

Comment: I tried that, it is prepared correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found out that my DB encoding was `LATIN2` and wordpress forced `UTF-8` in all calls after the update.

When I changed my database's encoding to `UTF-8` it all started to work. I also used:

```
$comment = mb_convert_encoding($comment, "UTF-8");
```

just to be shure.